# loading video file from torrent to html5 video

Tags: html, html5-video, libtorrent

Can  I  use  torrent file with   videos and this videos loaded in   ?
I have torrent with 3  videos. And  I have one simply  html page with video.js.

- Video 1:  Wellcome.wemb
- Video 2: Introduction.webm
- Video 3: What we  play.webm

So... Can I  load  first video  from torrent in video ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use torque. It's not pure javascript, but quite powerful.

http://torque.bittorrent.com/labs/

Check out http://onehash.com/ for an example of exactly what you want to do.

For a pure javascript implementation (I believe limited to chrome), check out jstorrent:

https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent

And here it is deployed: http://jstorrent.com/

Comment: Doesn't that require a plugin client side?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually or try writing some server software that extracts the torrent. If you find out how to do that, then try to do it ahead of time instead of each time at run-time.

Comment: So there is no way to use  JS to  get  video files from torrent.
tnx :}